# Detect failed user login attempts programmatically in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, authentication, pam

I need to detect all user login events including user authentication status (success/fail) from a C++ program. In other words, I need to detect all authentication success / authentication fail events.

I found online a few ways of doing this but each one has its own disadvantages:

1. Parsing the log files (`/var/log/auth.log` for example) but I find this quite inefficient to parse a text file and the format may be different from version to version.
2. Use audit subsystem to detect user activity but the audit subsystem is relatively new, and it may not be present on older machines
3. Use a PAM (portable authentication module) to detect user activity by injecting a `.so` in the authentication stack. Using this approach, I was able to nicely detect successful logins (by detecting the user "session start" event) but I'm struggling to detect the failed login attempts
   because there is no specific event for this.

My current implementation is capturing the "auth start" and "session start" events using a PAM plugin and consider that a login failed if the "auth start" is not followed by a "session start" within a time threshold. The time threshold must be pretty big in order to avoid false positive (at least as long as the password input timeout) and this makes this method to have a huge delay. I also tried to capture the custom PAM plugin unload event (by adding a module destructor function) but the `sshd` for example, does not close the forked process when the SSH connection is closed.

Is there any trick I can do with the PAM module (or another Linux feature / module) to detect, in real time, the user login failed events?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing btmp or utmp records may help . Those files are binary and there are lots of examples around about these.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.